# Cursor as full screen crosshairs

Tags: snow-leopard, applications, imac, display

I have a 27" iMac running Snow Leopard.  In a wide range of applications I often need to use a straight edge to compare different values on charts, even sometimes charts generated by different applications.  To do this I have made do with clumsy solutions like creating a floating and transparent Sticky or using <kbd>Shift + Command + 4</kbd>.  I've also tried a small app called Crosshairs.

None of these things do what I really want.  Ideally, I'd like a full screen crosshair centered on the cursor.  Another way to think about this, it would give me a full height vertical and full width horizontal line that would show up over (on top of) any and all applications, just as a cursor does. Nice to haves it would give the coordinates of the display and have toolbar or right click access to turn it on or off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SnagIt for Mac does exactly this: a full screen crosshair with pixel coordinates, when you take a screen shot. But it's only designed for screen shots. http://goo.gl/D0JnL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it has many more features than this, something like [xScope](http://xscopeapp.com/) sounds great for this.

Some main features:

- mirroring
- getting on screen dimensions
- rulers
- guides
- frames
- crosshair

Comment: Great little app.  WAy more than I need for what I do need of it works like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[QuickLens](https://quicklens.app/) has an excellent set of tools: a full screen live crosshair, movable/lockable guides, ruler and a few other measurement, magnification and alignment tools. Available via AppStore or as part of Setapp if you happen to subscribe to that.

[PixelSnap 2](https://getpixelsnap.com/) is a well designed app that provides great crosshair & measurement tools. It's a bit costly as a standalone app for just a crosshair, but it's included in Setapp as well.

[Red Lines Tools](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/red-lines-tools/id1469400117?mt=12) (App Store, currently free as of 2/2023). It has crosshairs, a magnifier, grid/image overlays, adjustable keybindings, and many other customizations. There are a few bugs but it gets the job done.

Another possible solution: [Monosnap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/monosnap/id540348655?mt=12) is a free screen capture app that displays full-screen crosshairs when capturing an area. You can trigger it via a hotkey and then hit ESC to cancel without actually taking a screenshot if all you want to do is use the crosshairs for alignment.

As others have mentioned, [xScope](https://xscopeapp.com/) is another option, although it's costly if all you need is crosshairs.

There *used* to be a small and efficient app called [Euclid](http://macdownload.informer.com/euclid/) written by Nicholas Jensen that was specifically for crosshairs. Unfortunately, it's been abandoned.

Comment: QuickLens recommendation proves timely, given that xScope now crashes Big Sur ;-( All said, I'd still prefer a simple crosshairs app.

Answer (score 1):

Free solution: Mouse Locator http://www.2point5fish.com/

You can make whatever custom cursors you want.

Hotkeys can turn it on/off, and if you want coordinates, you could launch Pixie (or another app) and keep it in the corner.

Comment: Does this provide a crosshair though? Reading through the description & screenshots on the website it doesn't appear so.

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach, you can try [Free Ruler for Mac OS X](http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/). This free application displays a horizontal and a vertical ruler, both of which you can extend. It supports different scales (cm, mm, pixels, inches, etc - it's using the screen DPI to display distance measurements correctly).

I use it quite often when I need pixel-perfect measurements of GUI elements, or other stuff and the application I work with doesn't give me what I need in terms of the measurements.

Please note, I'm NOT affiliated with the developer in any way, just a happy user for the occasional time that an application like this serves my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  xScope still does everything I need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Skitch](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap-mark-up-share/id425955336?mt=12) (a free screenshot annotation app) for the crosshair functionality. I have it set so that shift+command+5 brings up the crosshairs.