# Extending crosshair arms for partial screenshot on Mac OS

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I very frequently use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to take a partial screenshot and store it in the clipboard.

However, the arms of the crosshair which appears are very short, making it hard to select the right area on the first go, especially when I want to select a large area with no border.

So, I'm wondering whether it's possible to extend the arms of that crosshair, perhaps to span the entire screen?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. Good luck!

Comment: It probably is possible. Find the system resource icon that contains that crosshair, and modify it. Probably easier to to use a 3rd party tool though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cursor as full screen crosshairs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48515/cursor-as-full-screen-crosshairs)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, as it isn't the same question, nor does it have the same answer. Even if they did have the same answer, the question is different, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @daviesgeek I agree these questions are not duplicates, but I think they do have the same (or similar) answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to manipulate the system crosshair picker, however, [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) (free!) offers an alternative workflow for partial screenshots. They have a zoomed preview dialog, and the fully extended arms as you desire. Also free [in the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12).

[image: Skitch snapshot dialog]